# Looking for 16 Segment LED/VFD Display with Comma, Decimal Point, and circle

Tags: led, display

I am building a KITT replica from the TV show Knight Rider. On his dash are 10 characters of 16 segment LED's that have a decimal point and comma. In addition to that, there is a circle beneath each character. Can anyone identify where these LED's may have been pulled from back in the early 80's, or where they might be still available? My first thought is from a Speak and Spell game. 
[image]

Comment: Are you shooting for that much 1980s historical accuracy?  If not, you can buy modern 16- and 14-segment characters on [Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/Optoelectronics/Displays/LED-Displays-Accessories/_/N-6j73b/) and DigiKey.  (But no, they don't carry segmented characters from Predator's countdown clock.)

Comment: I suspect the "circle" underneath is just a standard round 3mm LED.

Comment: Found this site where he seems to have the correct characters. Said its from an old Fruit Machine? http://hackaday.soup.io/tag/vfd

Comment: Possibly from a Slot Machine

Answer (score 2):

Those are not actually LEDs. That is a 16-segment, 10-character [**VFD**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_fluorescent_display). You may be able to find an old pull, but they don't make them like that too much anymore.

**EDIT:**

Oh, maybe [you're in luck](http://www.noritake-itron.com/subpages/productse/Partsearchfull.htm) after all.